# Vue 3 - currency input filter

Tags: vue.js, currency-formatting, vuejs3

Does anyone know a library that converts number input to currency format and can be applied to Vue 3, because most use filters that are not currently supported in the Vue 3 version?

Comment: Vue 3 is newly released and many libraries are waiting for updates. You acted a little fast.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a combination of a computed property and [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) (or some currency npm package).

```html
<template>
    <div>{{costCurrency}}</div>
</template>

<script>
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'})

export default {
    props: {
        cost: Number
    },
    computed: {
        costCurrency() {
            return formatter.format(cost)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[vue-currency-input](https://github.com/dm4t2/vue-currency-input) supports Vue 3

Comment: Can you describe how? The initialization looks like Vue 2.